# Two function returning a value which is used in third function

Tags: javascript, function

```
first = function firstFunction(arg1){
    return arg1;
}

second = function secondFunction(arg2){
    return arg2;
}

final = function secondFunction(first, second ){
    return first + second;
}

first(10);
second(20);

final(first, second);
```

I wrote this code and here's what I understand of it.
Got three function first two return a value. first has the value it returned and second the same.

Now the third one is using two parameters, first and second. According to me first argument has value of 10 and second 20.

The third function is suppose to return first + second which is 30. But instead it returns this:

```
"function firstFunction(arg1){
    return arg1;
}function secondFunction(arg2){
    return arg2;
}"
```

Help, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not give the value as a parameter but you gave the functions itself. Try something like this:

```
final(first(10), second(20));
```

Another way to go:

```
var a = first(10);
var b = second(20);

final(a, b);
```

Comment: I'm already calling the function:
first(10);
second(20);

Why do I need to call them again?

Comment: You are calling them and they return a result, but you don't save it. You calculate it and that's it. You yould also safe their values, see my edit.

Comment: wow I thought just because I return the value the function name has that value assigned it to and can be used

Comment: No, functions exist to be used over and over again. Think of a "sqrt"-function in which you calculate once the squareroot of 4. Do you always want it to return 2? No. Thus you go ahead and always use the function with a parameter that specifies what you want it to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

```
function One(arg1){
    return arg1;
}
function Two(arg2){
    return arg2;
}
function Three(arg1, arg2){
    return arg1 + arg2;
}

let first = One(5);
let second = Two(5);
console.log( Three(first , second) );
```